# Application runs by Visual Studio vs. by executing an EXE file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

In C# we can use `Define Constants` to make some codes work or not work in each one like `DEBUG` by using `#if DEBUG`, Now I want to know is there any way like that for understanding that the application is running by pressing *Start* in Visual Studio (IDE) or is running by executing an EXE file?

I found this other ways:

- Using `app.config` and adding a special Setting and so on.
  In this case I need to edit my setting file too.
- Using `Define Constants` by adding a special constant and so on.
  In this case I need to change current constant.
- Using some additional files in the path of EXE file and check validation of them.
  In the case I need to use external files.

But I wonder about that is there any way to identify that the code is tracing by Visual Studio or not?

Also any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: `#define Constants` would only work if the executable is built that way. `Debug` build profile automatically adds the `DEBUG` defined constant which is why it works the way it does. So technically `#define constants` will not work for you because you need to recompile the executable each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the debugger is attached to the process with [`Debugger.IsAttached`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx). If executed with <kbd>F5</kbd> it is `true`, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> it is `false`, directly by explorer it is `false`, executed through other debuggers (non-Visual Studio) it should be `true`

Comment: When we press Ctrl+F5; does VS also runs EXE file?

Comment: @shA.t Yes, but the program isn't connected in any way to the visual studio (if you look at the title bar of VS, you'll see that there is no "Running")